# Custom js httphandler in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I'm trying wire up a custom IHttpHandler to process request to my website for *.js files. For the life of me I can't get my httphandler to even be created by IISExpress when a request is made for a js file to my web server. I've tried several variations of the system.webServer handlers setting including.

```
<add name="MyHandler"
       type="BusinessLayer.Web_Stuff.MyHandler, BusinessLayer"
       verb="*"
       path="*.js"
       resourceType="Unspecified"
       preCondition="integratedMode" 
       modules="IsapiModule" 
       scriptProcessor="c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"/>
```

and

```
<add name="JSHandler" 
     type="BusinessLayer.Web_Stuff.MyHandler, BusinessLayer" 
     verb="GET,POST" path="*.js"
     resourceType="Unspecified" 
     preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I am running this in Visual Studio 2013 using IISExpress. If i change the path to *.test instead of js then this handler works without any problems, but i cant make it work for *.js files. It seems like IISExpress is handling those requests itself by just serving the files off of disk. Does anyone know how to bypass that so i can make my handler process requests for js files.

**Correction**: When i use the top web.config setting with IsapiModule specified, an instance of MyHandler is instantiated however the ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) method of the interface is never called on my object. With the bottom definition, no instances of my handler are ever instantiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with this for several hours i finally found the answer. The key was I had to add an attribute to the modules xml element in system.webServer

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
```

Without this attribute, the process request handler was not being called. After setting that, this is all that was need in the handlers section.

```
  <add name="JSHandler"
       type="BusinessLayer.Web_Stuff.ScriptMinifyHandler, BusinessLayer"
       verb="*"
       path="*.js"
       resourceType="Unspecified"
       preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I will have to read a bit more about this setting, but if anyone can tell me more about why that works I'd love to hear it.